# What set of opening character parameters will give the easiest max level without accidental levels?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I would like to build an Oblivion character that has perfect leveling with a 5/5/1 (if possible, but if the 5/5/5 is easier I'll go for that), as I like to increase luck too. What is a build that will allow me to do this without really worrying too much about *accidentally leveling a skill* (for example it's easy to accidentally level athletics or if you're a jump-a-holic like me, acrobatics).

I'm looking for

- Race (would prefer one that looks more human, so Breton or Imperial, just because they look better, but would consider another race for strategic purposes.)
- Birthsign
- Custom class - 7 skills and spec.

I've done some preliminary research on it, which indicates you want to try to make your 7 skills be split among the 7 attributes. The first few are simple, but the others are more challenging.

- Agi - security: easy to control, just avoid locks when i don't want to level, and easy to level on queue by getting most of the tumblers, then exiting.)
- End - block: just don't block in combat, or do nothing but block in combat. Simple
- Int - alchemy: easy to control for obvious reasons
- Per - speechcraft: so easy to level it's ridiculous. I'm pretty good and fast at the wheel (was sad to see it go for Skyrim!!)
- Spe - ??
- Str - ??
- Wil - ??

The speed, strength, and willpower choices seem very difficult. They're much harder to control.

Right now I'm thinking speed could be light armor, and I can avoid leveling it by avoiding combat or playing without armor (it's really not that bad!)

For strength, I only get blade, blunt, or hand to hand. I can't really tell if I should have one, two, or none in my main spec, and just level these as offs. I really need strength to boost carry-weight of course. In my opinion it's the most important stat!

For willpower, I can choose between alt, dest, or rest. Rest you pretty much always need for combat. I almost never use alt when I play, but either that or dest would work as I can avoid using them pretty easy.

Comment: Have you considered just using a mod? I only ask because min-maxing is kinda weird in a single-player game.

Comment: One could make the case that min-maxing in any game is kinda weird, really. There are two reasons to aim for perfection in a game: one is to perform at peak potential, the other is because it's challenging, and challenges are entertaining. In this case, I'm doing it because it's challenging and entertaining. My wife would say that min-maxing at all, even in an online/multi-player game, is a waste of time. It's all about why you play a game! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oi, I built the perfect character once and it ruined the game for me. Instead of exploring and plundering a beautiful world I was obsessed with getting my stats perfect.

I pulled out my old spreadsheet and this is what I have for you, be warned though, by the time you finish leveling you might be sick of the game.

Here are the skills you want to choose

- Agility - Marksman
- Endurance - Armourer
- Intelligence - Alchemy
- Personality - Speechcraft
- Speed - Acrobatics
- Strength - Hand To Hand

Why these skills? Simple, you can control when you level with all of them.

Choose luck as a favoured attribute and the thief birthstone and you are on your way to maxing out luck.
You will want to put +5 into endurance every level until it is maxed out. This will ensure you get the maximum amount of HP.

Other than that you just need to keep an eye on which skills get raised like a hawk and try to only raise 2 stats at a time. (For this I use the spreadsheet)

Good luck!